# How to fix broken dropdown menu CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having problems creating a drop-down menu, the content doesn't fit inside the container
You'll see in the first picture what I want to create and what happen in the second image.

[image]
[image]

````css
```
  nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: 98%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav img {
  width: 165px;
}

.nav_links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav_links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 28px 22px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_links ul li a {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav_links ul li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav_links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: 270px;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:calc(85% + .15rem);
  padding: .75px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.dropdown li{
  position: absolute;
}
```
````

````html
```
  <nav>
        <a href="Index.html" id="logo"><img src="Images/cflogo_main.png"></a>
        <div class="nav_links" id="navLinks">
            <i class="fa fa-window-close" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Le collège</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li>Mot de la direction</li>
                        <li>Historique</li>
                        <li>Les enseignants</li>
                        <li>Calendrier scolaire</li>
                        <li>Fondation</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Vie scolaire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portail</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Admission</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
    </nav>
```
````

I'm still trying to understand positioning, but I've been trying this fix this one but I can't. Thanks in advance!
Edit : I was asked to show the problem, but even I I'm not sure where it is so I put all the header with the nav with the CSS

Comment: The output of the code you've provided doesn't seem to show the problem. Please edit your post and revise the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding on your list items can be adjusted as a possible solution to the spacing issues that are pushing them outside the desired space.

```css
  nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: 98%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav img {
  width: 165px;
}

.nav_links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav_links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  /*RIGHT HERE*/
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
   width: fit-content;
}

.nav_links ul li a {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav_links ul li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav_links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: 270px;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:calc(85% + .15rem);
  padding: .75px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.dropdown li{
  position: absolute;
 
}
```

```html
  <nav>
        <a href="Index.html" id="logo"><img src="Images/cflogo_main.png"></a>
        <div class="nav_links" id="navLinks">
            <i class="fa fa-window-close" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Le collège</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li>Mot de la direction</li>
                        <li>Historique</li>
                        <li>Les enseignants</li>
                        <li>Calendrier scolaire</li>
                        <li>Fondation</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Vie scolaire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portail</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Admission</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
    </nav>
```

Comment: So simple that I feel kinda dumb.. Thank you very much!

Comment: CSS can start to get lengthy at times making it difficult to discern where the problem actually lies. Glad we could get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use css `max-content`?

````css
body{
background-color:black

}
  nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: 98%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav img {
  width: 165px;
}

.nav_links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav_links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 28px 22px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_links ul li a {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav_links ul li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav_links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: max-content;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:calc(85% + .15rem);
  padding: .75px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.dropdown li{
  position: absolute;
}
```
````

````html
```
  <nav>
        <a href="Index.html" id="logo"><img src="Images/cflogo_main.png"></a>
        <div class="nav_links" id="navLinks">
            <i class="fa fa-window-close" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Le collège</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li>Mot de la direction</li>
                        <li>Historique</li>
                        <li>Les enseignants</li>
                        <li>Calendrier scolaire</li>
                        <li>Fondation</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Vie scolaire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portail</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Admission</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
    </nav>
```
````